# Django Rest Framework failing to patch Serializer(many=True).data in view test

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I'm unit testing a view and I am attempting to patch the `.data` property on my serializer but it looks like it behaves differently when the `many=True` kwarg is passed to the serializer constructor and thus not properly patching. Here is a generalized example of my code.

```
# myapp/serializers.py
class MySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    some_field = serializers.CharField()


# myapp/views.py
class MyView(View):

    def get(self, request):
        # ..stuff
        some_data = []
        serializer = MySerializer(some_data, many=True)
        print(type(serializer))  # <class 'rest_framework.serializers.ListSerializer'>
        print(type(serializer.data))  # <class 'rest_framework.utils.serializer_helpers.ReturnList'>


        return Response({"data": seralizer.data, status=200})


# in tests
def test_view_case_one(mocker):

    # setup other mocks

    serialized_data = mocker.patch("myapp.views.MySerializer.data", new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock)

    # invoke view
    response = MyView().get(fake_request)

    # run assertions
    serialized_data.assert_called_once() # this says it's never called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earlier I had ran into issues attempting to patch `rest_framework.serializers.ListSerializer.data`. Must of been a typo. Reattempted and was able to successfully patch. Given the case `many=True` recreates the serializer as a `ListSerializer` I simply needed to patch the property on the underlying class.

```
serialized_data = mocker.patch(
    "rest_framework.serializers.ListSerializer.data",
    new_callable=mocker.PropertyMock
)
```

**Edit: A more in depth answer**

When `many=True` is used the `__new__` method on `BaseSerializer` grabs you class and constructs a `ListSerializer` from it and that is why my object showed up as a `ListSerializer`. Since we are actually receiving a `ListSerializer` instead of our defined class the patch is not applied to `ListSerializer.data` method. The relevant parts of the source code for `BaseSerializer` is below

```
class BaseSerializer(Field):

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        # We override this method in order to automagically create
        # `ListSerializer` classes instead when `many=True` is set.
        if kwargs.pop('many', False):
            return cls.many_init(*args, **kwargs)
        return super(BaseSerializer, cls).__new__(cls, *args, **kwargs)

    @classmethod
    def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        This method implements the creation of a `ListSerializer` parent
        class when `many=True` is used. You can customize it if you need to
        control which keyword arguments are passed to the parent, and
        which are passed to the child.

        Note that we're over-cautious in passing most arguments to both parent
        and child classes in order to try to cover the general case. If you're
        overriding this method you'll probably want something much simpler, eg:

        @classmethod
        def many_init(cls, *args, **kwargs):
            kwargs['child'] = cls()
            return CustomListSerializer(*args, **kwargs)
        """
        allow_empty = kwargs.pop('allow_empty', None)
        child_serializer = cls(*args, **kwargs)
        list_kwargs = {
            'child': child_serializer,
        }
        if allow_empty is not None:
            list_kwargs['allow_empty'] = allow_empty
        list_kwargs.update({
            key: value for key, value in kwargs.items()
            if key in LIST_SERIALIZER_KWARGS
        })
        meta = getattr(cls, 'Meta', None)
        list_serializer_class = getattr(meta, 'list_serializer_class', ListSerializer)
        return list_serializer_class(*args, **list_kwargs)
```

Comment: Good catch on the "rest_framework.serializers.ListSerializer.data".

Comment: @JavierBuzzi Thanks. I had originally attempted that but I must of fat finger typo'd it or something as it didn't work. I think you can patch your serializer directly if it inherits from `ListSerializer` but I didn't verify. This would only work in the case that you always expect to pass a list to it.